# Knot Resolver: How to observe and modify a resolved answer at the right time

Tags: dns

## Goal

I would like to stitch up a GNU GPL licensed Knot Resolver module either in C or in CGO that would examine the client's query and the corresponding resolved answer with the goal of querying an external API offering a knowledge base of malware infected hostnames and ip addresses (e.g. GNU AGPL v3 [IntelMQ](https://github.com/certtools/intelmq)).

If there is a match with the resolved A's (AAAA's) IP address it is to be logged, likewise a match with the queried hostname should be logged or (optionally) it could result in sending the client an IP address of a sinkhole instead of the resolved one.

## Means

I studied [the layers](http://knot-resolver.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lib.html#lib-layers) and I came to the conclusion that the phase I'm interested in is `consume`. I don't want to affect the resolution process, I just want to step in at the last moment and check the results and possibly modify them.

I ventured to register the a [consume](https://gist.github.com/Karm/528470fdec582faf4bc2787c3edf7c82#file-sinkit-c-L3) function
with

```
static knot_layer_api_t _layer = {
    .consume = &consume,
};
```

but I'm not sure it is the right place to do the deed.

Furthermore, I also looked into module [hints.c](https://github.com/Karm/knot-resolver/blob/master/modules/hints/hints.c#L182), especially its `query` method
and module [stats.c](https://github.com/Karm/knot-resolver/blob/master/modules/stats/stats.c) for its `_to_wire` function usage.

## Question(s)

### Phase (Layer?)

When is the right time to step in and read/write the answer to the query before it's send to the client? Am I at the right spot in *consume* layer?

### Answer sections

If the following attempt at getting the resolved IP address gives me the Name Server's address:

```
char addr_str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
memset(addr_str, 0, sizeof(addr_str));
const struct sockaddr *src = &(req->answer->sections);
inet_ntop(qry->ns.addr[0].ip.sa_family, kr_inaddr(src), addr_str, sizeof(addr_str));
DEBUG_MSG(NULL, "ADDR: %s\n", addr_str);
```

how do I get the resolved (A, AAAA) IP address for the query's hostname? I would like to iterate over A/AAAA IP addresses and CNAMEs in the answer and look at the IP addresses they were resolved to.

### Modifying the answer

If the module setting demands it, I would like to be able to "ditch" the resolved answer and provide a new one comprising an A record pointed at a sinkhole.

How do I prepare the record so as it could be translated from `char*` to Knot's wire format and the proper structure in the right context at the right phase?

I guess it might go along functions such as `knot_rrset_init` and `knot_rrset_add_rdata`, but I wasn't able to arrive at any successful result.

THX for pointers and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to step in the last moment when the response is finalised but not yet sent to the requestor, the right place is `finish`. You can do it in `consume` as well, but you'll be overwriting responses from authoritative servers here, not the assembled response to requestor (which means DNSSEC validator is likely to stop your rewritten answers).

*Disclaimer: Go interface is rough and requires a lot of CGO code to access internal structures. You'd be probably better suited by a LuaJIT module, there is another module [doing something similar](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/knot-resolver/blob/master/modules/renumber/renumber.lua) that you may take as an example, it also has wrappers for creating records from text etc. If you still want to do it, that's awesome and improvements to Go interface are welcome, read on.*

What you need to do is roughly [this](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/knot-resolver/blob/master/lib/layer/iterate.c#L82-L87) (as CGO). 
That will walk you through RR sets in the packet (`C.knot_rrset_t`),
where you can match type (`rr.type`) and contents (`rr.rdata`).
Contents is stored in DNS wire format, for address records it is the address in network byte order, e.g. `{0x7f, 0, 0, 1}`.
You will have to compare that to address/subnet you're looking for - [example](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/knot-resolver/blob/master/lib/layer/iterate.c#L115-L131) in C code.

When you find a match, you want to clear the whole packet and insert sinkhole record (you cannot selectively remove records, because the packet is append-only for performance reasons). This is relatively easy as there is [a helper](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/knot-resolver/blob/master/lib/utils.h#L108) for that. Here's [code in LuaJIT](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/knot-resolver/blob/master/modules/policy/policy.lua#L138-L141) from `policy` module, you'd have to rewrite it in Go, using all functions mentioned above and using A/AAAA sinkhole record instead of SOA. Good luck!

Comment: Marek, could you give me a hint as to whether one should purge the whole packet ```knot_pkt_clear``` (with remembering msgid ```knot_wire_get_id```) or if it's actually correct to clear just the ```knot_rdataset_clear```? Given the following sequence makes sense:  ```knot_pkt_begin```, ```knot_rdata_init```, ```knot_wire_set_rcode```, ```not_wire_set_nscount```, ```knot_wire_set_id```, ```knot_wire_add_ancount```, ```kr_pkt_put```.

Comment: Records inserted to packet in libknot (and kresd) are serialised on-the-fly to avoid copies and slow label compression, so once you put a record in the packet there's no way to "undo" it other than clearing packet and starting anew. If you want to only append to packet, it's perfectly okay to just do what you described.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, lemme share my humble proof of concept that sinkholes whatever an external REST API call tells it to sinkhole, [knot-sinkit module](https://github.com/Karm/knot-sinkit). Disclaimer: The code is a prototype.  I'm considering either rewriting it in C or going for CGO.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work. I think you might find http://knot-resolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules.html#id9 interesting. You can say "daf.add 'src = 127.0.0.0/8 reroute 192.0.2.0/24-1.2.3.0'" and it's going to rewrite all addresses in answer matching subnet. For example "example.com A 192.168.0.2.1" will be rewritten to "example.com A 1.2.3.1" (works without subnets too).